# Relation between two independent Gaussian random variables

Tags: random-variables, gaussian

I am working on Gaussian comparison theorem. My question is as follows.

> **Question**.  Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent centered gaussian random variables. Let $Z=\sqrt{1-t}X+\sqrt{t}Y$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. And let $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\leq  \mathbb{E}[Y^2]$.  Then is it ture that there exists $a> 0$ and a random vector $W$ that is independent of $Z'$ such that $Z=aZ'+W$? where $Z'$ is a $t$ derivative of $Z$.

The related theorem is as follows. Please see the last paragraph of the page.

[image]

Comment: $EXY=(EX)(EY)=0$. with your aasumptions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ahh..... Thank you for the indication! I should edit my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $W=X$ and $\alpha=0$. This satisfies your requirements.

Answer for the revised version of the question:This is not always possible. Take $Y=X$. There is no $\alpha >0$ such that $X-\alpha X$ is indepndent of $\alpha X$.

Comment: Thank you ! But I want to see stronger result. I edited my question !

Comment: @LevBahn I have answered the new version also.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask for when $X\neq Y$? The proof I am studying uses somethin like this.  Let $X$ and $Y$ are independent Gaussian random variables and let  $Z=\sqrt{1-t}X +\sqrt{t}Y$. And suppose that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\leq \mathbb{E}[Y^2]$. Then there exists $a\geq 0$ and a random vector $W$ independent on $Y$ such that $Z=aZ'+W$.

Comment: The reason why I conditioned $\mathbb{E}[XY]>0$ is that, after some computation we get  $\mathbb{E}[ZZ']\geq 0$ due to the condition $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\leq \mathbb{E}[Y^2]$.

Comment: What is $Z'$ in yuor comment?

Comment: $Z $'is derivative of $Z$ with respect to $t.$

Comment: $W$ has to be $Z-aZ'$. It is  independent of $Y$ iff $E(Z-aZ') Y=0$ Solve for $a$  from this and see if $a >0$. @LevBahn

Comment: I am sorry. I made a mistake. I intended to say a random variable $W(t)$ is independent of $Z'$. But your argument make sense...